# Object TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing a bug that I can not resolve. I am building a blogging website as a side project. Right now I am trying to render a single post, but when I try to access object properties I get an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null**. I don't understand why object properties are null, event though I can print the object itself. Here are the code snippets:

This is a PostView Component that will handle rendering of the post content. I can print in the console the post object that I receive from the api but when I try access or print its properties like title, body and etc... I get an error. At first I thought I had an error in redux reducers and actions but it seems it's works fine. The states are changing and and I receive the json response. I used similar code for my other components and it worked, so I don't understand where I am making the mistake here?

```html
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPost} from 'actions/post';

//Components
import PostContent from '../Content/PostContent';

//Material Ui 
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';




const PostView = ({ getPost, post: {post: { title, body, category }, loading }, match}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getPost(match.params.id);
    },[getPost]);
    
    //This code works
    console.log(post);
    //But this one does not
    console.log(post.title);

    return (
            <Grid container>
                <PostContent/>
            </Grid>
    )
}

PostView.propTypes = {
    getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost })(PostView)
```

Here is also my actions function:

```html
//Get Post by Id
export const getPost = (id) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${id}`);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_POST,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }catch(err){
        dispatch({
            type: POST_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
        });
    }

};
```

And the post reducer file:

```html
import{
    GET_POSTS,
    POST_ERROR,
    UPDATE_VOTES,
    ADD_POST,
    GET_POST,
    GET_POSTS_IMAGE,
    POSTS_IMAGE_ERROR
} from '../actions/types';


const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: null,
    loading: true,
    status: true,
    error: {}
}



export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case GET_POSTS:
            return{
                ...state, 
                posts: payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case POST_ERROR:
            return{
                ...state, 
                error: payload,
                loading: false
            } ;
        case UPDATE_VOTES:
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: state.posts.map(post => post._id === payload.postId ? { ...post, upVotes: payload.upVotes} : post),
                loading: false
            };  
        case ADD_POST:
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: [...state.posts, payload],
                loading: false,
                status: false
            };
        case GET_POST:
            return{
                ...state,
                post: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am only learning react and redux, so any help will be appreciated.**strong text**

Comment: Since your destructuring the props in `PostView`, shouldn't it be `console.log(title);` to log the title value? Unless I'm missing something, `post` shouldn't even be defined in that block.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null.` indicates that at some point, you are reading a property from a value of `null`, which will cause an error.

From your code, you are setting the initial state of `post` to `null` in the reducer, as a result, there is a moment where the prop `post` is `null`, the error originates from this moment.

`post` only updates to a non `null` value (assuming the ajax call will response with some data), and can be safely accessed after the `getPost` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because your Redux initial state of `post` is null and you are trying to read some property of null.

Try to add some conditionals, like:

```js
if(post && post.title) {
  console.log(post.title)
}
```

Or change your Redux initial state :

```js
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: {
      title: "",
      body: "",
      ...etc
    },
    loading: true,
    status: true,
    error: {}
}
```